# Python - Performing changes on max/min values of list of tuples

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I have the following list of `(x,y)` tuples:

```
[(0, 0), (36, 0), (0, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]
```

The tuples with the smallest `x` I would like to iterate `x+1` and the tuples with the smallest `y` I would like to iterate `y+1`. This should produce the following:

```
[(1, 1), (36, 1), (1, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]
```

Since the smallest `x` and `y` are both 0, we change them to `0+1`.

Analogically, I want to do a similar thing for the biggest `x` and `y` => biggest `x` should change to `x-1` and biggest `y` should change to `y-1`.

The final output after performing those two changes should be:

```
[(1, 1), (35, 1), (1, 35), (4, 19), (19, 4), (35, 35)]
```

What would the most efficient way for performing that be? I will be working with lists with more than 1000+ elements so time-efficiency is key.

Comment: Please give it a try and show us your code, with a report on whether its performance is adequate, and if not, by how much it needs to be sped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the minimal x and y values first.

```
>>> lst = [(0, 0), (36, 0), (0, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]
>>> min_x = min(x for x, y in lst)
>>> min_y = min(y for x, y in lst)
>>> min_x
>>> 0
>>> min_y
>>> 0
```

Then, iterate over `lst` and add `1` to each coordinate that is equal to their respective minimum value.

```
>>> lst = [(x + (x == min_x), y + (y == min_y)) for x, y in lst]
>>> lst
>>> [(1, 1), (36, 1), (1, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]
```

Note that adding `True` to a number adds `1`, adding `False` to a number adds zero, e.g.

```
>>> 36 + True
>>> 37
>>> 36 + False
>>> 36
```

You can proceed in analogous fashion for the second part of your question, using the `max` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the most efficient way for performing that be?

This is a good example where, if you *can* use a 3rd party library, vectorised operations are helpful. For example, using Pandas, you can use Boolean indexing with a column:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [(0, 0), (36, 0), (0, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)

for col in df:
    df.loc[df[col].eq(df[col].min()), col] += 1

print(list(map(tuple, df.values)))

[(1, 1), (36, 1), (1, 36), (4, 19), (19, 4), (36, 36)]
```

That said, ~1000 elements is a relatively *small* number, so there's no *guarantee* the structural overhead of Pandas will be offset by vectorisation benefits.